# Как изменить файл(cart.js) который отображает мини-корзину на другой html странице?

Tags: javascript

Я сделал сайт. На сайте можно добавить товары в корзину и отфильтровать товары (цена, страна-производитель, размер)
Вот этот проект:

https://codesandbox.io/s/great-bardeen-p7v7f

На этом сайте файл **eshop.js**, что он исполняет:
1) отображает мои товары на страничке man.html или woman.html а берет их в **goods.json**
2) добавляет товары в mini-корзину (на тую же страничку)

а также файл **cart.js** что он испоняет:
1) он отображает товары на страничке **cart.html** что добавлены в мини корзину
2)на страничке cart.html можно прибавлять или удалять товары.

Но добавилась задача в **eshop.js** сделать фильтр товаров что фильтрует товары по разным свойствам объектов, а также фильтр который выводит товары в зависимости какую html страницу открыли man.html / woman.html. Сделал фильтр но потребовалось весь файл eshop.js изменить и после изменений **cart.js** перестал работать и на отдельной страничке корзины(cart.html) уже не выводится добавление в mini корзину товары.Его надо изменить как-нибудь но я не знаю как, я только начал изучать в JS.

Вот так хочу чтобы было

http://i.piccy.info/i9/fab9a0f92b65e...334636/sk2.jpg

Как изменить **cart.js**? Что дописать или переделать чтобы работал код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Картинка по ссылке у меня не открылась 
2) В песочнице в файле "cart.html" `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">` файл "style.css"  ищется в папке "css", в то время как у тебя файл стилей называется "styles.css" и лежит в папке "src" то есть должно быть так `<link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css">`

```
<script src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/cart.js"></script>
```

3) При импорте файлов "cart.js" и "jquery-3.1.1.min.js" он ищет их в папке "js" в песочнице нет ни папки ни соответственно файлов.

Что бы помочь тебе настроить работу корзины нужен как минимум скрипт её работы.

П.С. На будущее, если ты задаешь вопрос и хочешь ответов, то когда получаешь ответы не игнорируй ответчиков и их ответы, отмечай как правильные если тебе помогли.

Comment: я уже исправил но не в этом причина, просто там полностью надо переделать файл, я даже немного сделал, но не полностью

Comment: @vrm111 а где этот файл то? добавь его в песочницу.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-euler-8esty
К сожелению код не работает.
Но я создал отдельную песочницу написал только cart.js (тот файл) и cart.html так как мне нужна старая песочница в таком виде как она есть пока-что. Но если как подскажете как клонировать старую песочницу то добавлю к клонированой.

Comment: просто использую старую песочницу на другом форуме, могу сбросить если вам надо ссылку на форум

Comment: Нажми на кнопку Fork в правом верхнем углу и будет тебе клон. Мне то не надо, это только если ты заинтересован в ответе.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-moser-i2heh 
добавил в песочницу cart.js и cart.html

Comment: что вы скажете?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-maxwell-ixpw9 чуток исправил ваш код. еще можешь в благодарность стрелочку вверх нажимать и на ответе и на комментах.

Comment: ого) спасибо огромное!

Comment: Есть проблема, пробую запусить в текстовом редакторе код и товары не отображаются ни на страницах man.html и woman.html, ни в корзине на cart.html
В консоли пишет что проблема в строке:
import $ from "jquery";
Причем в обоих файлах, такая проблема и в eshop.js и в cart.js
Но может причина не только в этом.
Можете открыть код в каком-то текстовом редакторе и посмотреть в чем проблема?

Comment: удали эту строчку везде

Comment: спасибо большое!